# Row-oriented or column-oriented?: Databricks database tables

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

Are the tables within Databricks databases stored in a row- or column-oriented arrangement?

*(cross-posted at https://forums.databricks.com/questions/45981/row-oriented-or-column-oriented-databricks-databas.html)*

Comment: what kind of tables? Delta?

Comment: @AlexOtt No, just standard Databricks tables, i.e. https://docs.databricks.com/data/tables.html. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 1):

Databricks stores tables in Delta Lake format by default. If you don't tell it to store as `csv` or `json` etc. it will wind up in `.parquet` files. (Delta Lake is mostly Parquet with some extra metadata and a log)

Given that, it is more accurate to describe it as column oriented than row oriented.

Comment: Well parquet is actually row-column oriented. It's splittable by row groups, ans each one is column oriented.

Comment: Funny the [Apache Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org) site says: "Apache Parquet is an open source, column-oriented data file format..."

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/demystifying-the-parquet-file-format-13adb0206705